# Strapi GraphQL query: "start" argument wouldn't work

Tags: strapi

I am running into a very strange problem with my queries in Strapi (version **3.0.0-alpha.26.2**). I have a `users` collection with 3 documents that I'm trying to fetch via GraphQL. To fetch all users the query is:

```
users {
  firstName
}
```

This returns the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "firstName": "Arnold"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Bill"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Vin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

3 names. Now, say, I wished to retrieve only the first 2 users. For such pagination use-cases, there's two arguments one could pass in a Strapi query: `start` (defines the index to start at) and `limit` (defines the number of elements to return). So now the query would be:

```
users(start: 0, limit: 2) {
  firstName
}
```

This returns the first two names as expected:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "firstName": "Arnold"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Bill"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But what if I want the last 2 users here, i.e. **Bill** and **Vin**? Should be as straightforward as:

```
users(start: 1, limit: 2){
  firstName
}
```

But this still returns **Arnold** and **Bill**, while you'd expect the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "firstName": "Bill"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Vin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

No matter what value I use for `start`, it always starts at the 0th item. You could do `start: 200` (when there are only 3 items in the `users` collection) and it'd still return the exact same result! What sorcery is this??

The issue can be reproduced at https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql.

Comment: Hello! strapi is now on beta.16.6 and this issue is fixed.

Comment: So was it a known issue?

Comment: Was an issue in the version of strapi you use yap. 
I suggest you update your app.
You will find migration guide in the strapi documentation.

Comment: do you mind implementing this? are you working on numbered pages?